# Why does the iOS Simulator show only a blank view/window?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ios-simulator

I'm new to iOS development. I used the Interface Builder to add text fields and buttons to my view. When I run the app, the iOS Simulator only shows an empty beige screen. What am I missing? The console doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you have not connected your view to your File's Owner.

To do this Right Click on the View, Control Click on the Oultlet of your View and drag it to the File Owner.

This  shall solve your problem.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it's because you have AutoLayout turned on in your storyboard, but haven't set any constraints.

Follow my instructions in the following article, to confirm if this is true.

[AutoLayout problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338623/ios-app-only-showing-half-in-simulator/28338944#28338944)

Basically, with XCode 6, if you have AutoLayout turned on, you *must* set constraints on *every single* control... otherwise your screens will look fine within XCode, but the controls in your screen could (and will) end up anywhere and in any size when the app is run.

It's like designing a beautiful webpage, then displaying it in an angry, drunk, disorientated browser.

XCode is *really* unintuitive, and unhelpful for beginners... but once you learn the rules of AutoLayout (along with its many quirks), it's reasonable useful.